# Why did this compile?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, null

The code below compiled without a problem. It's clear `_dependency` will always be `null`, so it's not possible to use it in any way (aside from evaluating it) - is it? Why was the compiler not aware of this and fail it?

```
public class MyClass
{
   private readonly MyDependency _dependency;

   public MyClass()
   {
      _dependency.MyMethod();
   }
}
```

To be clear, I know the code above is bad code, and it is the developers fault - but as is any other compile-time error. I would've thought the compiler would've thrown a `use of unassigned variable` kind of error.

Why did this compile? Am I unaware of a scenario whereby it would be fine to use a `null` object like this?

EDIT:

To confirm - I am *not* wishing to rely on the compiler to check for poorly written code - and I appreciate that, syntactically, it is absolutely fine. My question really is two-fold, is there a scenario which I'm unaware of which may make this code execute fine. And the second question is - why *wouldn't* it detect such an issue, if it already deals with `use of unassigned variable` errors? What's the difference?

Comment: Is `MyDependency` declared as class or struct?

Comment: This cause run-time error. properties (unlike local variables) have default value assigned. so there is no compile time error `use of unassigned variable`

Comment: Because null is a valid (and default) value for a class

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - you're correct, it gave me a runtime error. But surely this runtime error could've been anticipated at compile-time, which is why I ask.

Comment: @Johan - of course, but I'm attempting to use it in a way that a `null` object could never be used. I would understand how `_dependency == null` would compile, but surely it's aware that `_dependency.MyMethod()` would be called on a `null` object, no?

Comment: Assuming that `MyDependecy` has a method named `MyMethod`, there's nothing wrong with the code. It's not compiler's job check if an object was initialized or not. This is done at runtime or using 3rd tools to hint (like Resharper).

Comment: No. even in method you can assign null into local variable and use it without getting compile-time error. when you assign null explicitly you tell compiler "dont mess up with this. ill handle it"

Comment: The compiler doesn't do null checking so you are essentially asking why the compiler does not have a given feature which is not really meaningful, Features are added from a baseline of no features, not removed from some set of ideal features you thin k it should have.

Comment: @BenRobinson - so why do we have `use of unassigned variable` errors? Both share the same notion - that the compiler is aware of the path of execution, and aware that such path will throw a null reference exception. What's the difference to what I'm describing?

Comment: you may ask why `null` exception is not compile-time error? what if the value is set by multi threading? i think thats why compiler does not check for null.

Comment: Imagine `MyMethod` would be extension-method (of course, they have not been introduced in old C#1-days). Compiling this code calling `MyDependency.MyMethod(null)` would be expected to compile, wounld´t it?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - that's the kind of answer I'm looking for, multi-threaded environments - I didn't think of that. This is why I asked the question - is there a scenario I'm unaware of that makes this code 'ok'? Or is it simply a feature that hasn't been implemented in the compiler?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - syntactically it's fine, yes. But look at `_dependency` - it's never assigned a value. So the call to the extension method will never work.

Comment: Tools like resharper can find out this situation and will warn you. But thats just warning. It may be true or not. compiler can get buggy if it throws run time exception at compile time. There may be many reasons that this code will work. Multi threading, reflection, use of unmanaged library or managed library etc....

Comment: @JayMee calls to extension methods on `null` instances work just fine.

Comment: By reflection you can set the read-only field and you can execute the constructor afterwards. This is how deserialization works as well: if a type implements `ISerializable`, it will be created without any constructor, then the `[OnDeserializing]` method is executed, and only after that will be be special constructor with `SerializationInfo` and `StreamingContext` parameters invoked. See my answer as well.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - nice! The kind of input I was after. I didn't realise that, after further research I can see why.

Answer (score 7):

Because the compiler doesn't check for that kind of issues. It's syntactically correct, and perfectly fine. Null reference issues are usually only detected on runtime, unless you use code analysis tools that will detect that kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As per my comment to Ben, there is at least *some* feature of the compiler which checks the path of execution - as we have `use of unassigned variable` errors - I'm failing to see the difference in that scenario to the scenario I'm describing. It's no big issue - I'm just curious as to why the compiler hasn't detected a problem.

Comment: Unassigned variables are only checked for local variables in the function body.

Comment: a variable that is never used isn't an error so doesn't stop compilation its just stripped out by the optimiser, if you enable code analysis in your project settings then you will get more detailed checking for bad practice

Comment: @JayMee because there is no "local" problem. The problem is with the class taken in its entirety, which is orders of magnitude more difficult to detect that the usual compiler errors. There is a set of compiler tools to do this work, Code-Contracts, but its incredibly slow to run.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's not strictly incorrect. Maybe a warning, but definitely not a compiler error.

You can do this for example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly MyDependency _dependency;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _dependency.MyMethod();
    }

    public bool IsDependencyNull()
    {
        return _dependency == null;
    }
}

public class MyDependency { public void MyMethod() { } }
```

Then using it:

```
var c = (MyClass)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(MyClass));
c.IsDependencyNull().Dump();
```

Gives the result 'True'

Answer (score 1):

First of all, code editor aids might give you a *warning* that the field is not assigned and it *may* work wrong.

[image].

Secondly, you cannot test in compile time whether the members are accessed by reflection. You can assign the field, even if it is read-only. You can even invoke the constructor after you initialized the read-only field externally. Consider the following example:

```
// creating an instance without executing the constructor
MyClass myClass = (MyClass)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(MyClass));

// setting the read-only field
myClass.GetType().GetField("_dependency", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .SetValue(myClass, new MyDependency());

// invoking the constructor on the already existing myClass
ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(MyClass).GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
MethodInfo mi = typeof(RuntimeMethodHandle).
    GetMethod("InvokeMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
object signature = ctor.GetType().GetProperty(
    "Signature", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(ctor);
mi.Invoke(null, new []{myClass, null, signature, false});
```